# Create a heatmap using gnuplot froma a matrix written on a . txt file

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap from a .txt file.

If this matrix is taken from a python matrix `data` and written on file using `numpy.savetxt(file,data)`, when using gnuplot to create the heatmap with the command:
`plot 'heat.txt' matrix with image` I get an all black map without getting an error from gnuplot.

If I instead create the matrix directly filling it with `data=numpy.matrix('...;...')` and then save it with `numpy.savetxt(file,data)`, when using gnuplot with the same command it works fine.

Unfortunately it's not possible to fill the matrix I need manually because of its dimensions.

Thank you in advance

...

heat.txt  with google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0CY3UaQmc3AVzhfUVY2dDhpbjg?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post the content of he file `heat.txt` that gnuplot doesn't seem to be able to plot? Does gnuplot create any error message or warning when you try to plot?

Comment: I added the file

Answer (score 0):

The majority of your data is in the range between 0.97 and 1.3. However, the last column of your data file is all 0, and the second-to-last column is all 400. Therefor gnuplot uses the range [0,400] for your plot, and you cannot see any signal from your data.

You should either leave out the last two columns of your plot, or set the range manually:

```
set cbrange [0.97:1.3]
plot "heat.txt" matrix w image
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much